# PHP server only run 300 seconds

Tags: php, vps, ini, max-execution-timeout

I have a vps server, and set the `max_execution_time` as 0 in whm and cpanel, but php crawl script just only runs 300 seconds, even though I set the `set_time_limit` as 0 or 1000.

`ignore_user_abort` is also the true.

Where is the problem? Is it the problem with server setting?
I checked phpinfo, `max_execution_time` is 0 in local and master value.
Found many answers in here,but not found any right one.
Welcome your answer and advising.

Comment: have you amended the correct ini file?

Comment: This is webserver, not php related.

Comment: yes, fixed ini file correctly. I reached all answers related with this for 3 days

Comment: Webservers will usually end the connection after 5 minutes. If you need a script to run longer, it's best to run it via the command line.